# Passing functions to a class

Tags: c++, class, templates

Suppose I have this class:

```
template<class K, class func1, class func2>
class findMax {
    K* key;
    func1 cmp;
    func2 areSame;
};

template<class K, class func1, class func2>
findMax<K, func1, func2>::findMax(K n, func1 isValid, func2 areSameFunc) {

    cmp = isValid;
    areSame = areSameFunc;
}
```

How do I make an instance of this class?

I have tried:

```
typedef bool (*someFunc)(int);
typedef bool (*someFunc2)(int, int);

findMax<int, someFunc, someFunc2> u(7, isValid, areSame); // Doesn't compile, error below.
```

Error message:

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
 findMax(const findMax<int,bool (*)(int, int),bool (*)(int)> &)
 findMax()
 findMax(int, #10000, ?, ?)
'
```

where:

```
bool isValid (int k) {
    return (k>0);
}

bool areSame (int key, int key2) {
    return key==key2;
}
```

But this doesn't work. I have tried other approaches as well but couldn't find how to do this. 
How do I do it then?

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Sorry, added.

Comment: @SomeoneWithAQuestion Use `std::function` with c++ code.

Comment: @SomeoneWithAQuestion _`// Doesn't compile`_ isn't very informative. Post a [MCVE] and verbatim error messages in your question.

Comment: You defined the constructor but you never declared it in the class...

Comment: I did declared, I just didn't post the entire code and forgot to add.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Is there a solution without using C++11 features?

Comment: I think the compiler is telling you that  you swapped 1-arg and 2-arg functions in your call to the constructor. It expects 2-arg to be first.

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort out your constructor declaration/definition and probably also your declaration of the member (it probably should be a value rather than a pointer). With that it should be straight forward to create the objects.

Personally, I wouldn't actually both specifying the template arguments but rather create a suitable factory function. For example:

```
template<typename K, typename Fun1, typename Fun2>
class findMax {
    K     key;
    Fun1 cmp;
    Fun2  areSame;
public:
    findMax(K n, Fun1 isValid, Fun2 areSameFunc)
        : key(n)
        , cmp(isValid)
        , areSame(areSameFunc) {
    }
};

template<typename K, typename Fun1, typename Fun2>
findMax<K, Fun1, Fun2> makeFindMax(K n, Fun1 fun1, Fun2 fun2) {
    return findMax<K, Fun1, Fun2>(n, fun1, fun2);
}

bool isValid (int k) {
    return (k>0);
}

bool areSame (int key, int key2) {
    return key==key2;
}

int main() {
    auto obj = makeFindMax(7, isValid, areSame);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. findMax is actually in a header file, and the rest of the code I posted is in the source file. Is there a way I can make this without having to call another function from my source file to create a new `findMax`?

Comment: @SomeoneWithAQuestion: there is nothing wrong with declaring the factory function in the header, too. However, once you correctly defined your constructor you can just call it as is done in `makeFindMax()`.